# HTML truncated by POST request C#

Tags: c#, html

I've developed a method that returns a HTML string by POST.
My method works fine but only when the HTML string is small. If the HTML string is large the result will be truncated.
For example:
If the HTML string has a table with 500 rows, the result is perfect!!!
But If the HTML string has a table with 1000 rows, the result only returns 600 rows.

This is the URL: www.aduanet.gob.pe/cl-ad-itconsmanifiesto/manifiestoITS01Alias?accion=cargarFrmConsultaManifiesto&tipo=M

The inputs are 2013 y 788, you can try manually.

I've added the timeout parameter but the problem is the same. 
I hope that you can help me, please.

```
public String mtHTML()
        {
            string tcuri = "http://www.aduanet.gob.pe/cl-ad-itconsmanifiesto/manifiestoITS01Alias?accion=consultarxNumeroManifiesto";
            string tcparameters = "CMc1_Anno=2013&CMc1_Numero=788&CG_cadu=118&TipM=mc&CMc1_Terminal=";
            StringBuilder lcsb = new StringBuilder();
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(tcuri) as HttpWebRequest;
            httpRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 60000;
            httpRequest.Timeout = 60000;
            httpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            // Parameters(TextView)
            string postData = tcparameters;
            httpRequest.ContentLength = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(postData);
            httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch");
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8");
            httpRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
            httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36";
            httpRequest.Referer = "http://www.aduanet.gob.pe/cl-ad-itconsmanifiesto/manifiestoITS01Alias?accion=cargarFrmConsultaManifiesto&tipo=M";
            string tcCookie = "ITCONSMANIFIESTOSESSION=JTpnS9cFJJCvBBYsCV4JFfdc2w9L8JbYdh125SnBmkjwK3WxbD6MrPPPhdF9XRYbLJBW31qn29CcVp7QbSWYBST7wYrh7Zz43Qhh0pzF7JYG1wlJKKQ1qJzLJ3vMWz1Cf6mNNLp8b09TcJBpWHtnsyJp26nyJS7p1tGFW29Wt1Mz4KVHmgTChLVGphlzHx57Yxgf1f6g7w2JdZqhVz4JttJDhnbvDv9yDmsMcRVdwQm1JYrlG0twwLHZvnXMkYz9!517535082!NONE";
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", tcCookie);

            using (Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                byte[] parametersBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
                requestStream.Write(parametersBuffer, 0, parametersBuffer.Length);
            }
            string responseText = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                using (WebResponse httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                }               
            }
            catch (WebException wex)
            {
                if (wex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                {
                    using (var response = ((HttpWebResponse)wex.Response)) 
                    {                        
                        try
                        {
                            //Descomprimimos el resultado
                            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new GZipStream(response.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress));
                            lcsb.AppendLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                        }
                        catch (WebException ex) { throw; }
                    }
                }
                //throw new Exception(sb.ToString(), wex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw; }
            return lcsb.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I get an exception "The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly." when running your code.

Comment: You get this exception because your cookie was expired, this URL has many validations, you need you updated the cookie value in the code. [link](http://www.aduanet.gob.pe/cl-ad-itconsmanifiesto/manifiestoITS01Alias?accion=cargarFrmConsultaManifiesto&tipo=M) This url generate a new cookie in  the header to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Use this config:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:1000000
```

Or See

[Limit WebClient DownloadFile maximum file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616358/limit-webclient-downloadfile-maximum-file-size)

[Is there a limit on the size of a http argument value in a HttpWebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557663/is-there-a-limit-on-the-size-of-a-http-argument-value-in-a-httpwebrequest)

Comment: Hi Shahrooz, I've used your config, but the result is the same, even I've put the following parameter <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20000"/> in the web config but nothing.